# Headers using ajax request

Tags: html, jquery

How to set headers using Ajax request? in below code

```
$.ajax({
    type: type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: requestURL, // Location of the service        
    //  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // content type sent to server

    dataType: "xml", //Expected data format from server
    processData: false, //True or False
    success: successCallback, //On Successfull service call
    error: serviceFailed// When Service call fails
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Request headers can be managed using `beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)` function and the `setRequestHeader` method, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  beforeSend  : function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  }
});
```